# Problems with CherryPy url-encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, cherrypy

im trying to get german umlaute in my url variables.
This is my code:

```
class Root:
    def echo(self,input):
        return input
    echo.exposed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),'/')
```

This works fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/echo/?input=äöüß
```

Result: **äöüß**

But when i try:

```
http://localhost:8080/echo/äöüß
```

I get: **Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã**

Does anyone know the reason and how i can fix this?

Comment: Is the webserver throwing any exceptions?

Comment: No, but it seems like for some reason it gets converted to latin1... If I write **return input.encode('latin1')** i get the correct output with _http://localhost:8080/echo/äöüß_ but ??? with _http://localhost:8080/echo/?input=äöüß_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import cherrypy

class Root:
    def echo(self,input):
        return bytes(input, 'Latin-1')
    echo.exposed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),'/')
```

or do this:

```
class Root:
    @tools.encode(encoding='Latin-1')
    def echo(self,input):
```

Cherrypy is by default encoded utf-8.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it works, but isn't there away to get utf-8 input?

Comment: Well in my top example the input is coming in utf-8 by using bytes I convert it to Latin-1 which show your umlaute correctly.  You could also do this:  cherrypy.config["tools.encode.encoding"] = "Latin-1"

Comment: but why isn't it displayed correctly in utf-8 if I use the human readable url?

Comment: when i go to localhost:8080/echo/äöüß; the query_string_encoding is set to utf8.  This article explains it well. http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/refman/_cpreqbody.html#module-cherrypy._cpreqbody "Some processors, especially those for the ‘text’ types, attempt to decode bytes to unicode. If the Content-Type request header includes a ‘charset’ parameter, this is used to decode the entity. Otherwise, one or more default charsets may be attempted, although this decision is up to each processor."

Comment: @AndrewKloos your link to the doc is broken. New working link to the same document: http://cherrypydocrework.readthedocs.io/pkg/cherrypy.html#module-cherrypy._cpreqbody